# How to read bank credit card by ios's NFC function at system version 13.2

Tags: ios, iphone, nfc

My boss said at iOS beta version 13.2 can read bank credit card info by iPhone's NFC function. But I don't know how to achieve it.
What I know might work method is NFCTagReaderSession, but it doesn't work at following codes:

```
[self.tagSes invalidateSession];
self.tagSes = [[NFCTagReaderSession alloc]initWithPollingOption:NFCPollingISO15693 delegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

if (NFCTagReaderSession.readingAvailable) {
    self.tagSes.alertMessage = @"send card to phone's back";
    [self.tagSes beginSession];
} else {
    NSLog(@"no support NFC");
}

- (void)tagReaderSession:(NFCTagReaderSession *)session didDetectTags:(NSArray<__kindof id<NFCTag>> *)tags{
    NSLog(@"%@\n",tags);
    self.curentTag = [tags firstObject];
    if (self.curentTag.type == NFCTagTypeMiFare) {
        id<NFCMiFareTag> mifareTag = [self.curentTag asNFCMiFareTag];
        NSData *data = mifareTag.identifier;
        NSLog(@"data:%@",data);//** 1. there can print card type is NFCMiFareTag **
        [session connectToTag:self.curentTag completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"fail:%@",error);//** 2. then ,in here throw a fail,tell me connect break **
                return ;
            }
            [mifareTag readNDEFWithCompletionHandler:^(NFCNDEFMessage * _Nullable messages, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                NSLog(@"--->>%@,%@",messages,error);
                NSArray *ary = messages.records;
                for (NFCNDEFPayload *rec in ary) {
                    NFCTypeNameFormat typeName = rec.typeNameFormat;
                    NSData *payload = rec.payload;
                    NSData *type = rec.type;
                    NSData *identifier = rec.identifier;
                    NSLog(@"TypeName : %d",typeName);
                    NSLog(@"Payload : %@",payload);
                    NSLog(@"Type : %@",type);
                    NSLog(@"Identifier : %@",identifier);
                }
            }];
        }];

    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.nfcw.com/2019/06/10/362961/apple-to-let-iphone-owners-use-nfc-to-read-all-types-of-contactless-card-except-for-payments-cards/

Comment: So this problem can't be solved, right?